# How can I filter RadioButton choices based on another field in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using read-admin. https://marmelab.com/react-admin . I have a ReferenceArrayInput field named "**Members**" for selecting multiple values. I also have a RadioButtonGroupInput named "**Manager**" whose choices depend upon the values selected for "**Members**" i.e **Manager** can only be one of the **members**. How do I display only the selected members as options in **Manager** field? I used FormDataConsumer to get current form values and use the members as choices in manager field. But it shows all the operators as choices.

Here is my **file.jsx**

```
export const MyCreate = (props) => {

  return (
    <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        
        <ReferenceArrayInput
          source="members"
          reference="operator"
          label="Members"
        >
          <SelectArrayInput optionText='name'/>
        </ReferenceArrayInput>

        <FormDataConsumer>
          {({ formData, ...rest }) => (
            <ReferenceInput
              source="manager"
              label="Manager"
              reference="operator"
            >
              <RadioButtonGroupInput
                optionText="name"
                choices={formData.members}
              />
            </ReferenceInput>
          )}
        </FormDataConsumer>

      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<FormDataConsumer>
   {({ formData, ...rest }) => (
      <RadioButtonGroupInput
          optionText="name"
          source="manager"
          choices={formData.members}
      />
   )}
</FormDataConsumer>
```